# How to include CSS and JS once in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, templates, assets, laravel-blade, laravel-elixir

I am building a large Laravel 5.2 application. We are using a number of 3rd party libraries (such as jQuery, D3, and others).

I could combine the libraries as a single file (with Elixir), but since most of the pages won't need the full set, I would like to keep them separate. The templates are complex, and I want an easy way to make sure a CSS/JS file is included, but only once.

Currently, in our master template, we have stacks for CSS and JS, and we push onto the stack, for example:

@push( asset('path.js') )

But, this doesn't give a good way to ensure the file included once, so I would like something like

@pushonce( asset('path.js') )

I couldn't find any extensions that provide this. Are there any extensions that provide this? Do I need to implement it myself? Or are we taking the wrong approach (this can't be a unique problem).

One thing that makes the app special is users might be in slow connections (2G) and we have to cross the China Firewall, so I'm hesitant to concatenate all into a single file (file size makes a huge difference).

Comment: you could use angular with laravel, some kind of lazy load you should do for each page to load only those files(js/css) which actually needed to php page.

Comment: If you create multiple files you will be forcing users to download several different vendor files. If you create just only one, although it might be bigger they will be cached, so the users don't have to download them so often. This is one of the things there is no correct answer, you have to profile your application and figure it out which one makes more sense

Comment: You could create a facade called `Asset` and then anytime you need an asset you could do `Asset::push('path.js')`.  At the bottom of your main  template then could make an `Asset::render()` function that prints each unique item in the list once.

Comment: @FabioAntunes I agree and I don't have that answer yet. We will also deploy very often which can mean caches get invalidated on such a regular basis that is can be more advantageous to break things apart.

@Jeff Thanks for the idea - this is similar to my idea which was to extend the existing `stack` blade to check if the items has already been added.

Comment: @fabio The smaller files would also be cached.

Comment: @Garret Don't try to deal with the stack mechanism to achieve your goal here. [Stacks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#stacks) contain template data, html and such. Validating for unique scripts in that would be super annoying. You should try what Jeff mentioned and create a Facade that has an includeScriptOnce type function that takes a path to a file as a string instead. Much easier to validate for uniqueness.